Can I align equations within eqnarray
I have an array of equations. If I use the following code:
\begin{align} 
    &\Gamma^{\rm Monopole}_{ab} = 1, \label{eq:monopoleORF} \\ 
    &\Gamma^{\rm Dipole}_{ab} = \cos\xi_{ab},\quad \mathrm{and} \label{eq:dipoleORF} \\ 
    &\Gamma^{\rm HD}_{ab} = \frac{\delta_{ab}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{(1-\cos\xi_{ab})}{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\nonumber \\
    &\hspace{1cm}-3\log\left[\frac{1-\cos\xi_{ab}}{2}\right]\bigg) \label{eq:HDORF},
\end{align}

then they look like this:

which I think it what I want.
However, when I try to upload to arxiv, using align seems to really mess up the formatting of the paper. So instead, I am using:
\begin{eqnarray} 
    &\Gamma^{\rm Monopole}_{ab} = 1, \label{eq:monopoleORF} \\ 
    &\Gamma^{\rm Dipole}_{ab} = \cos\xi_{ab},\quad \mathrm{and} \label{eq:dipoleORF} \\ 
    &\Gamma^{\rm HD}_{ab} = \frac{\delta_{ab}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{(1-\cos\xi_{ab})}{4}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\nonumber \\
    &\hspace{1cm}-3\log\left[\frac{1-\cos\xi_{ab}}{2}\right]\bigg) \label{eq:HDORF},
\end{eqnarray}

which produces:

Is it possible for me to still use eqnarray (which arxiv seems to be happy with) but also align the \Gamma symbols at the beginning of each equation?
Here is how it looks when arXiv processes my files:

Lots of white space.

With {eqnarray} you need two starting &. However, I never had problems with {align} on arXiv, so something is strange. What exactly is the problem? Note also that \rm has been more or less deprecated for at least 20ish years.

what do you mean by arXiv is unhappy they use a standard texlive. Also note that \rm has not been defined by default in latex since 1993, you really shouldn't be using it in any document written in the last 30 years.  The use of eqnarray is wrong as you have all of the expressions in the middle column designed for =

@campa out by 10 :-)

Thanks both. I have changed \rm to \mathrm. I have attached an image to show what is happening when arXiv processes my files.

Another oddity (irregularity?!) about the output of the eqnarray-based approach you report is that -- see eq. (6) -- the \frac expressions appear to be processed in text-style rather than in display-style math mode. If you wish to proceed with eqnarray (and I don't think you should), be sure to replace all four instances of & with && (as that'll fix the \frac sizing issue.

If you need more information about why eqnarray should be avoided at nearly all cost, please see the posting eqnarray vs align and especially this highly-upvoted answer.

I have now broken the equation into three and so am no longer using eqnarray. It's still not aligned as I want though. Strange that arXiv displays it fine when I use equation but not when I use align.

Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

Does the following code, which assumes that the document is typeset in two-column mode and uses both an align and an aligned environment, work satisfactorily with your arXiv-bound paper?

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'align' environment

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{3} % just for this example

\begin{align} 
&\Gamma^{\mathrm{Monopole}}_{\!ab} = 1\,, 
   \label{eq:monopoleORF} \\ 
&\Gamma^{\mathrm{Dipole}}_{\!ab} = \cos\xi_{ab}\,,
   \text{ and} 
   \label{eq:dipoleORF} \\ 
&\begin{aligned}[b] % place equation number on bottom row
   \Gamma^{\mathrm{HD}}_{\!ab} 
   &= \tfrac{1}{2}(\delta_{ab}+1)
    -\tfrac{1}{4}(1-\cos\xi_{ab})\\
   &\quad\times\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}-3\log\bigl[
      \tfrac{1}{2}(1-\cos\xi_{ab})\bigr]\bigr)\,. 
   \end{aligned}
   \label{eq:HDORF}
\end{align}

\end{document}


Judging from the OP's image, the output is supposed to be in two-column format.

@egreg - Ah, I hadn't noticed this so far. Let me rewrite my answer.

Thank you @Mico, but yes whenever I use {align} the arXiv version of the manuscript looks very wrong with lots of white space. I suppose I must be doing something wrong elsewhere.

@user1551817 - This is very strange. Please edit your query to post a screenshot of what you get when you compile my version of the equations on arXiv.

@Mico I have changed the screenshot in my answer. My equation (3) is fine if I use equation for all equations. But if I use align for equations (4) (5) and (6), then I get all that white space around (3) as well as (4) (5) and (6). (1) and (2) still seem to be fine in either case.

@user1551817 - Have you run \allowdisplaybreaks?
